# Maven command for Sonarqube analysis

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, builds, build-pipeline, hudson

I am planning to build a Maven project in Jenkins. I tried to do some research how to give goals for Maven for doing few steps in one command but cant get understood how to do.

What I mean is how can I give a goal where Maven can build Maven project like creating artifact, skip tests and analyse Sonarqube analysis with particular URL like (`sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://url`)?

I tried but I am unable to give all goals at same time. I am planning to give in these three steps in three different goals. Any way that I can give in single step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can pass multiple goals to maven in command line simply by passing them as arguments. 
[Skipping test require a java system property](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html) that you can also pass as an argument to the command line.

For packaging a maven artifact, executing a sonar analysis with the maven goal but skipping executing the tests you should use :

`mvn package sonar:sonar -DskipTests`

Before that, you need to decide if you want to put sonar settings in the maven configuration (i.e. `pom.xml` or `.m2/settings.xml`) or in the Jenkins server configuration.

- With maven only, the `sonar:sonar` goal needs some requirements and maven configuration that you can find [here in the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven). Jenkins use will be reduced to execute maven, you won't need to install a Jenkins plugin.
- Using Jenkins with sonar also needs some requirements and Jenkins configuration that you can find [here in the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwiththeSonarQubeScanner). Be sure to install the Sonarqube scanner Jenkins plugin. This plugin enable some Jenkins integration features.